# Sleeping barber, semaphores?

Tags: java, multithreading, semaphore

I've been trying to solve this for two days now and I finally give up, I'm posting my code here with the hope that some fellow human can provide me with what I have been missing, because I think I am close, please help!

Code For Barber:

```
public Semaphore customer = new Semaphore(0);
public Semaphore barber = new Semaphore(0);
public Semaphore accessSeats = new Semaphore(1);
public int freeChairs = 5;

@Override
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        try {
            customer.acquire(); //it seems the barber never acuires a customer, even after the semaphore is released
            accessSeats.acquire();
            freeChairs += 1;
            cutHair();
            barber.release();
            accessSeats.release();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex){}
```

Code for Customer:

```
    public void run() {
    while (notCut) {
        try {
            bs.accessSeats.acquire();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {}
        if (bs.freeChairs > 0) {
            bs.freeChairs -= 1;
            bs.customer.release();
            bs.accessSeats.release();
            try {
                bs.barber.acquire(); //the customer cant get past this line
                getHaircut();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {}
        } else {
            bs.accessSeats.release();
            notCut = false;
        }
    }
}
```

I create 1 barber and 100 customers on a random timer.

EDIT: `cutHair()` sleeps the barber thread for 1-5 seconds (random). and `getHaircut()` just prints a message, and sets `notCut=false;`

Comment: Do you see any exceptions ? looks like you are only catching exceptions. at least print the stacktrace.

Comment: I do print, but removed them since I wanted to make the code easier to read.

Comment: what do the cutHair() and getHaircut() methods do? Does anything throw an InterruptedException?

Comment: Can you post the full code ?

Answer (score 0):

[`Semaphore`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) is a counting semaphore - you should read the javadoc for more info. The problem is that you're never telling the `barber` `Semaphore` that there's an available `Barber`. So it will never allow an `Customer` to acquire it.

Solution:
When you create a `Barber`, the first thing you do is to call `barber.release()` (before the while-loop!) or initialize `barber` with 1 permit.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a proper answer, but there are several things that look wrong here:

1) freeChairs should be an AtomicInteger.

2) It looks like you are setting notCut = false in the wrong block - surely that should be set after getHaircut()? (try naming the boolean 'cut' and initialize it to false. The double-negatives make it harder for humans to process!)

3) Lots of the semaphore aquires and releases should be atomic with respect to eachother but are not. eg

```
barber.release();
accessSeats.release();
```

Looks like it should be atomic - another thread should never be able to see the state where the barber semaphore has been released but the accessSeats hasn't, but this isn't the case here. That can lead to deadlocks unless you are very careful about the order you call aquire / release on the different semaphores.